# SQL script with IF ELSE not working properly

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I'm using SQL Server 2000. There is a table called `trialbalance_diff`. The structure is shown below.

```
accno       des                 month   diff

1010011001  Cash in Hand          5     -732230.0
1030033001  Seylan Bank           4      309042.0
1050011001  Lease Debtors         2        9899.0
1050011002  Lease VAT Suspense    5        2240.0
```

I need these data to be re-written to another table called `temp_TB_Diff`. The field `Diff` should be inserted according to the month. Like this,

```
acc_code    Acc_desc               Jan           Feb       Mar      Apr     May

1010011001  Cash in Hand                                             -732230.0
1030033001  Seylan Bank                                    309042.0
1050011001  Lease Debtors               9899.0
1050011002  Lease VAT Suspense                                          2240.0
```

I wrote this SQL script for this.

```
DECLARE @month int;

SELECT @month = [month] FROM trialbalance_diff

BEGIN 

IF @month = 1
    INSERT INTO temp_TB_Diff(acc_code, acc_desc, jan)
    SELECT accno, des, diff FROM trialbalance_diff
ELSE IF @month = 2
    INSERT INTO temp_TB_Diff(acc_code, acc_desc, Feb)
    SELECT accno, des, diff FROM trialbalance_diff
ELSE IF @month = 3
    INSERT INTO temp_TB_Diff(acc_code, acc_desc, Mar)
    SELECT accno, des, diff FROM trialbalance_diff
ELSE IF @month = 4
    INSERT INTO temp_TB_Diff(acc_code, acc_desc, Apr)
    SELECT accno, des, diff FROM trialbalance_diff
ELSE IF @month = 5
    INSERT INTO temp_TB_Diff(acc_code, acc_desc, May)
    SELECT accno, des, diff FROM trialbalance_diff
ELSE IF @month = 6
    INSERT INTO temp_TB_Diff(acc_code, acc_desc, June)
    SELECT accno, des, diff FROM trialbalance_diff
ELSE IF @month = 7
    INSERT INTO temp_TB_Diff(acc_code, acc_desc, July)
    SELECT accno, des, diff FROM trialbalance_diff
ELSE IF @month = 8
    INSERT INTO temp_TB_Diff(acc_code, acc_desc, Aug)
    SELECT accno, des, diff FROM trialbalance_diff
ELSE IF @month = 9
    INSERT INTO temp_TB_Diff(acc_code, acc_desc, Sep)
    SELECT accno, des, diff FROM trialbalance_diff
ELSE IF @month = 10
    INSERT INTO temp_TB_Diff(acc_code, acc_desc, Oct)
    SELECT accno, des, diff FROM trialbalance_diff
ELSE IF @month = 11
    INSERT INTO temp_TB_Diff(acc_code, acc_desc, Nov)
    SELECT accno, des, diff FROM trialbalance_diff
ELSE IF @month = 12
    INSERT INTO temp_TB_Diff(acc_code, acc_desc, [Dec])
    SELECT accno, des, diff FROM trialbalance_diff

END
```

It works except for one small problem. The data doesn't get inserted to specific months. The values which are supposed to go to different month columns get inserted to only one column.

It looks like this,

```
acc_code    Acc_desc            Jan      Feb       Mar       Apr        May

1010011001  Cash in Hand                                             -732230.0
1030033001  Seylan Bank                                               309042.0
1050011001  Lease Debtors                                               9899.0
1050011002  Lease VAT Suspense                                          2240.0
```

What am I missing in the script that causes this? I can't seem to figure out why.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

A scalar variable is just one value. Which row do you think populates the variable when you assign it? SQL Server is going to pick an arbitrary row. In this case it chose 5, so only one of your queries were executed. Brute force simple way is:

```
INSERT INTO temp_TB_Diff(acc_code, acc_desc, Jan)
    SELECT accno, des, diff FROM trialbalance_diff WHERE Month = 1;

INSERT INTO temp_TB_Diff(acc_code, acc_desc, Feb)
    SELECT accno, des, diff FROM trialbalance_diff WHERE Month = 2;

INSERT INTO temp_TB_Diff(acc_code, acc_desc, Mar)
    SELECT accno, des, diff FROM trialbalance_diff WHERE Month = 3;

...
```

Comment: this will only insert one row for May month

Comment: @Vikram: You are probably confusing this with something else. There's nothing wrong with this solution and all the rows where `Month` is `5` will be selected and inserted, same with other months.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand i really got confused :)

Answer (score 1):

use case statement as follows:

```
 INSERT INTO temp_TB_Diff
    SELECT 
    accno, 
    des, 
    case when month = 1 then diff end as jan,
    case when month = 2 then diff end as feb,
    case when month = 3 then diff end as mar,
    case when month = 4 then diff end as apr
    ....

    from trialbalance_diff
```